# gwtquery logs to console: RETTT. What does it mean?

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

Fairly frequently, I see this in my browser console:

`RETTT`

I couldn't find anything relevant in a Google search, and the only hint at what this might mean comes from:

```
if (JsUtils.isDefaultPrevented(event))
```

in `com.google.gwt.query.client.plugins.events.EventsListener.onBrowserEvent(Event event)`

Why is that in there? What does it mean? Any idea what it stands for?

I am using `GWT 2.7` and `gwtquery 1.4.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was some meaningless logging used in debugging just to know the `if` statement was executed. It was removed in [this](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery/pull/340/commits/57c1dbd68ce52b97789784ff16eae2d333f59789) commit which was merged into version 1.4.4.